# Charging series connected Li-pos one-by-one

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I wish to charge a 4s li-po battery cell by cell, with a charger for 1s li-ion/li-poly charger (TP4056). I know this isn't a problem electrically, since only one electrode of the adjacent battery will be connected, but I'm wondering if  applying some arbitrary voltage on the battery material will create some kind of chemical reaction that will degrade the battery?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYvVxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you have a floating supply compared to the battery, this should work but please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you are proposing since the devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using a floating supply just in case. Out of curiosity, what will be the problem if "B-" is ground referenced?

Comment: Thanks for the schematic. If your TP4056 B- is ground referenced and your battery is floating then no issues. If your bottom cell is ground referenced too, then you have just short circuited three cells.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to fly my quad while waiting for a proper replacement charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a isolated supply this should not pose any problems.

However in human factors terms this is not a good idea. In order to keep a balanced battery pack you have to remember to charge all of the battery cells. In the absence of a Battery Management System (BMS) this could lead to the over discharge of one or more cells, during the discharge phase, leading to a dangerous situation the next time you try to charge it.

With care this situation will be avoided however it is my experience that if you present an opportunity for error then errors will happen.